# Parsing $_REQUEST keys with php. How to optimize the code?

Tags: php, parsing

Starting from this $_REQUEST

```
var_dump($_REQUEST) ... 
  'LDCM' => string '' (length=0)
  'LDCS' => string '' (length=0)
  'UB:1@UBO' => string '1' (length=1)
  'UB:1@INV:2@INVN' => string '2' (length=1)
  'UB:1@INV:2@INVD' => string '2' (length=1)
  'UB:1@INV:2@INVC' => string '' (length=0)
  'UB:1@INV:1@INVN' => string '1' (length=1)
  'UB:1@INV:1@INVD' => string '1' (length=1)
  'UB:1@INV:1@INVC' => string '' (length=0)
  'UB:1@INV:3@INVN' => string 'sdfsdf' (length=6)
  'UB:1@INV:3@INVD' => string 'sdfsdf' (length=6)
  'UB:1@INV:3@INVC' => string '' (length=0)
  'PRVS' => string '' (length=0)
  'PRVR' => string '' (length=0)
  'PRVP' => string '' (length=0)
...
```

I want to obtain a resulting array ($insertArray) like

```
print_r($insertArray) ... 
    [LDCM] => 
    [LDCS] => 
    [UB] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [UBO] => 1
                    [INV] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [INVN] => 2
                                    [INVD] => 2
                                    [INVC] => 
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [INVN] => 1
                                    [INVD] => 1
                                    [INVC] => 
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [INVN] => sdfsdf
                                    [INVD] => sdfsdf
                                    [INVC] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [PRVS] => 
    [PRVR] => 
    [PRVP] => 
..
```

Mantaining element order.

This is my working code

```
$insertArray = array();
$elementKeysCounter = array();
$elementMap = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, '@') === false) {
        $insertArray[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $elements = explode('@', $key);
        $buildingKey = '';
        $buildingExp = '';
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            if (strpos($element, ':') !== false) {
                $buildingKey = ltrim($buildingKey . '@' . $element, '@');
                $revBuildingKeyParts = explode(':', strrev($buildingKey), 2);
                $buildingKeyClean = strrev($revBuildingKeyParts[1]);
                if (!array_key_exists($buildingKey, $elementMap)) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($buildingKeyClean, $elementKeysCounter))
                        $elementKeysCounter[$buildingKeyClean] = 0;
                    else
                        $elementKeysCounter[$buildingKeyClean]++;
                    $elementMap[$buildingKey] = $elementKeysCounter[$buildingKeyClean];
                }
                $elementParts = explode(':', $element);
                $buildingExp .= "['" . $elementParts[0] . "'][" . $elementMap[$buildingKey] . "]";
            } else {
                $buildingExp = '$insertArray' . $buildingExp . "['" . $element . "']=" . '$value;';
                eval($buildingExp);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Someone is able to semplify or optimize the code?**

I don't like the strategy I used (starting from the central use of eval() function).

Comment: can't you just send the data with the structure that you want? i.e `?UB[0][INV][0][INVN]=2`

Comment: unfortunately I can't..